# Using LIKE with IN / OR in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 where I am trying to replicate a simple query of

```
SELECT Col1, Col2 
FROM Table
WHERE Col1 LIKE 'A%'
    OR Col1 LIKE 'B%'
    OR Col1 LIKE 'C%'
```

as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_MySP
    @ColValues varchar(100) = NULL
AS
SELECT Col1, Col2 
FROM Table
WHERE (@ColValues IS NULL OR Col1 LIKE (????))
```

Unable to replace ??. Basically I want to use **LIKE** with **IN** / **OR**. Any help?

Comment: I don't think you could do LIKE IN ('A%', 'B%', 'C%'). Is the number of possible values known?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number of parameters is unknown, then you will need to do a table operation. Basically something like

```
select
    col1,
    col2
from
    Table t
    inner join MyParameters p on (t.Col1 like p.Query)
```

In order to generate table `MyParameters`, you can either construct it in your code, or use the new [table-valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) in 2008.

Comment: Or a CTE ;WITH MyParameters (select 'a' ...)

Comment: I think Table Valued Parameters is what should resolve my query. Still working on the implementation part, so not marking it as answer. But will surely do it. Right now +1. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I created a table inside my stored procedure and joined it to get my final outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Will it work for you :

```
WHERE  Col1 LIKE '[A,B,C]%'
// or for A,B,C you can just write
WHERE  Col1 LIKE '[A-C]%'
```

Comment: `SELECT 'abc' LIKE '[A,B,C]%'` returns 0 in MySQL, is this a T-SQL specific feature?

Comment: @Johan : Yeah, it works in sql server only. But the question was about SQL Server, not MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ParseString (@string varchar(500), @delimeter char(1))
RETURNS @valuelist table (
  -- columns returned by the function
  value nvarchar(255) NOT NULL
)
begin
  declare @pos int
  declare @piece varchar(500)

  –- Need to tack a delimiter onto the end of the input string if one doesn’t exist
  if right(rtrim(@string),1) <> @delimiter
   set @string = @string  + @delimiter

  set @pos =  patindex('%,%' , @string)
  while @pos <> 0
  begin
    set @piece = left(@string, @pos – 1)

    insert into @valuelist (value) VALUES (@piece)

    set @string = stuff(@string, 1, @pos, '')
    set @pos =  patindex('%,%' , @string)
  end
end

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_MySP
    @ColValue1 varchar(100) = NULL
    ,@ColValue2 varchar(100) = NULL
AS
SELECT distinct Col1, Col2 
FROM Table
inner join parsestring('a,b,c')
WHERE col1 like concat(value,'%');
```

Comment: I think he wants to be able to pass all of the values in as one parameter.